# Buscar por diretórios específicos contendo o caminho por completo

Tags: python, python-2.7

Fala galera,

Estou precisando de uma ajuda para listar todos os diretórios que contenham "_novo", por exemplo:

`/var/www/site_novo/teste` já iniciei o código para pegar os diretórios _novo, ele encontra os mesmos, porém preciso que ele me retorne o caminho por completo como no exemplo anterior, mas ele esta me devolvendo apenas uma lista com ['site_novo1', 'site_novo2'] segue código abaixo:

```
import re

rx = re.compile(r'_novo')

print(list(filter(rx.search, os.listdir('.'))))


Que me devolve a seguinte saída:

['site_novo1', 'site_novo2', 'site_novo3']
```

Porém gostaria que me retorna-se com o path todo.

Att,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar o glob.glob() do python para pegar todos os nomes das pastas e com os.path.abspath() .
Exemplo:

```
import os
import glob
a = glob.glob("*_novo") #Lista com os nomes das pastas que contem _novo
os.path.abspath(a[0]) # Caminho absoluto até a pasta do primeiro item da lista a
```

No glob tem o recursive que pega todas as pastas e arquivos que tem dentro das pastas, mas pra cada coisa que ele encontra ele adiciona uma posição no array. Exemplo:

```
a = glob.glob("*_novo//**", recursive=True)
```

segue a doc do glob: https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda man!

Comment: Opa, qualquer coisa estou ai.

Answer (score 0):

Olá você pode tentar da seguinte forma

```
dirs = list(filter(rx.search, os.listdir('.')))
[dir for dir in dirs if dir.find('_novo')>=0]
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela contribuição!